# Prevent Adding Marker Out of Image Using Leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet

I'm using Leaflet.js for my project. I want to add markers on map click and save them.

```
var newMarker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
```

I'm adding markers with code above. But I want to prevent adding markers out of my image. How can I do that ?

Comment: "out of my image?"Which image? An `L.imageOverlay`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply define the [bounds](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds) of your image (e.g. if you want to use the [current map view](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-getbounds), you would do `var bounds = map.getBounds();`), then use a conditional statement to check whether the click event position is [contained](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-contains) within those bounds before creating the marker:

```js
var imageBounds = map.getBounds();

function addMarker(event) {
    var newPosition = event.latlng;

    if (imageBounds.contains(newPosition)) {
        // You do not need the "new" if using "L.marker"
        // on the contrary of "new L.Marker" (note the uppercase)
        var newMarker = L.marker(newPosition).addTo(map);
    }
}

map.on("click", addMarker);
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation on here https://jsfiddle.net/xbv7q41n/2/ but it not worked. when my zoom is 1 i can put marker out of image.

Comment: You copied the `map.getBounds` which was just an example, since it was unclear which image you wanted to use. Obviously since you already have computed your image bounds (variable `bounds`), that is the one that you should use in place of `imageBounds` from the above code. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xbv7q41n/3/